# How do I cast a string so that I can read the string as hex values?

Tags: c

If I'm given a string "192f3c", how to I manipulate this string so that I am able to read it as the hex values "19", "2f", and "3c"?

I'm programming in C.

///////////////////////////

sorry for the confusion. Hopefully this will clarify.
I'm trying to compare a hash value with a given hash value.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* hashing done here with sha1 and stored in "value" */

    if (argv[1] == value) {
        printf("%s\n", "hash matches");
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", "hash fails");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

so the general gist is if do "./a.out 3f3c" it will tell me if the hashed value matches the input value.

problem comes in when I try to compare a string to the actual hash value which is in hex. So I'm trying to figure how to convert one or the other so I can compare the two.

Comment: Get two characters at a time, put in another string?

Comment: Is there a way to take those 2 character that's currently a string and treat it as a hex value?

Comment: You're supposed to show us the code you've written so far and explain where the error is. The function you're looking for, though, is `sscanf()`.

Comment: Do you want a printout like this: "19 2F 3C" ... with each byte separated by a space?

Comment: From the example input (`"192f3c"`) do you want three *strings* each containing two characters, or do you want three *integers* (`char`, `int`, `unsigned` etc)? What is your use-case? What are you going to do with the three separate "numbers"?

Comment: There's no cast to obtain a result such as splitting a strings or converting it in a number ... you may write (or use, if already exist) a function!

Comment: Is `value` a string of hex digits? Then just compare the two strings (using [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)). If it's an integer variable (e.g. `unsigned long value`) then convert `argv]1]` to the same type using [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) and compare normally.

Comment: I believe "value" is an array of hex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple and basic way to isolate every 2 characters is to declare a pointer to your input and keep a counter. You can use the modulo `%` operator to only act on every other character allowing you to isolate every 2nd. You can use the same logic with `sscanf` to read each hex byte into a numeric value or an array of values. The following gives an example of both:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* check for required input */
    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s <string of hex vals>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *p = argv[1];
    unsigned val = 0;
    size_t n = 1;

    printf ("\n Original string: %s\n\n", argv[1]);

    /* print every 2 characters */
    while (*p) {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
            printf ("   %c%c\n", *(p-1), *p);
        n++;
        p++;
    }

    printf ("\n As unsigned values:\n\n");

    p = argv[1];
    n = 1;
    /* read every hex bytes into values using sscanf */
    while (*p) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            sscanf (p-1, "%2x", &val);
            printf ( "   0x%2x\n", val);
        }
        n++;
        p++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/str2hexpairs 192f3c

 Original string: 192f3c

   19
   2f
   3c

 As unsigned values:

   0x19
   0x2f
   0x3c
```

**Note:** whether printing or reading into values, when using a pointer to parse the hex pairs, you will always read two characters (effectively reading one hex byte), and then print or fill your unsigned value by using the pointer position `p - 1`. This is to prevent an inadvertent read beyond the end of your string in the event you have an odd number of characters (less than a full hex byte at the end your string)

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for a library function use [atoh](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref%2Fa%2Fatoh.html) from stdlib.h

Answer (score 0):

Try this : ( I am getting error in few cases. But works for most part). I appreciate corrections to this code:

```
    int ascii_to_hex (char c)
{
    int num = (int) c;
    if (num < 58 && num > 47)
    {


        return num - 48;
    }
    if (num < 103 && num > 96)
    {


        return num - 87;
    }
    return num;
}


int main ()
{

    unsigned char a[] = "192f3c";
    unsigned char *hex_arr;
    int i,j;
    char c;
    int sum;
    unsigned char c1,c2;

    hex_arr = malloc (sizeof (a)/2);

    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof (a) ; i = i+2)
    {
        c1 = ascii_to_hex (a[i]);
        c2 = ascii_to_hex (a[i+1]);
        sum = c1 << 4 | c2;
        hex_arr[j] = sum;
        j++;
    }

    printf("Array in hex\n");

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof (a)/2 ; i++)
        printf("%.2X ",hex_arr[i]);


    printf("\n");
}
```

O/P:

> > Array in hex
> >
> > 19 2F 3C